# Call Java Methods in Eclipse Plugin from C# program

Tags: c#, java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, communication

I have written a C# program which has to call two methods in an eclipse plugin process.

I need an idea on how to realize the communication between the C# process and the java process.

Comment: Sorry, but what does your architecture look like?

Comment: I'd like to activate a task in Mylyn from an external C# program.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Sockets or else Inter Process Communication (IPC) Structures (more [here](http://www.cs.um.edu.mt/~jcord/SystemsProgramming/CourseMaterials/10_SimpleSynchronousIPCCommunication.pdf)). The best one depends on what you are doing and how you are doing it, which is not something you are exposing in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this: [Ikvm](http://www.ikvm.net/)
 its a JVM that's implemented in .net  and it provide several tools to help the development.